# Problems running pyxbgen

Tags: python, xml, xsd, pyxb

Running W10. Python3.2.3. Downloaded PyXB-1.2.4.tar.gz
at a prompt ran "python setup.py install"
Everything appears to be installed correctly. When I run pyxbgen I received file is not recognized... I search the drive only to find a file pyxbgen without an extension. I ran the setup process again, it looks like it validated the setup. What step did I miss? Why am I missing the executable?

Answer (score 3):

pyxbgen is a Python file without the ".py" extension, so Windows doesn't treat it as executable. You have to invoke the Python interpreter with something like :

```
C:\Python34\python.exe pyxbgen ...
```